# Getting value of clicked checkbox with JQUERY and pass it to ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

When I click a checkbox I want to make a post request using ajax

My checkboxes look like this:

```
<input name="foton" type="checkbox" onclick="processForm(this)" 
value='.$f->group_id.'>Închis</input>
```

My JS function looks like this:

```
function processForm(e) { 
    jQuery.ajax( {
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/ajax/checkbox.php',
    data: { foton : jQuery(e).val()},
    success: function(data) {
        jQuery('#message').html(data);
    }
    });
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the current syntax. Since you are passing the object itself from the onclick event, you don't need to convert it to a jquery object to get it's value. Simply `this.value` would give the underlying value.

```
 data: { foton : e.value},
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
function processForm(e) { 
    $.ajax( {
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/ajax/checkbox.php',
    data: { foton : e.value },
    success: function(data) {
        jQuery('#message').html(data);
    }
    });
}</script>
```

I believe you should be able to utilize e.value to pass in your checkbox value. However, this is tough to troubleshoot because I don't know what your problem is.

Answer (score 1):

Another answer is to move it all to JQuery and pass the JQuery Element. Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/tb5tfL2b/4/

```
function processForm(e) { 
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/ajax/checkbox.php',
        data: {
            foton: e.val()
        },
        success: function(data) {
            $('#message').html(data);
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("input[name='foton']").on("click", function() {
    processForm($(this));
  });
});
```

Or switch to when it is changed vs clicked: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/tb5tfL2b/5/